# Clustering 1-gram Strings

Tags: machine-learning, clustering, similarity

I have a big list of mail addresses (around one million) and I want to use/adapt/create an algorithm to find similarities between them (basically to cluster them).

All the algorithms I've checked so far e.g. n-grams variants, bag of words etc. are only used for clustering strings that are part of a context but here is not the case.

So far I've tried ***Levensthein***, ***LCS***. Both of them are pretty accurate but I'm interested in an algorithm that uses machine learning techniques, if such an algorithm exists for this task. Also they are pretty slow for my dataset.

Comment: What current clustering did you use? And why do you say you want one that uses machine learning techniques? Wasn't your first technique already machine learning?

Comment: @ValentinCalomme I want to see the differences between non ml and ml techniques, like, what are my options. I said I just checked those techniques (n-grams, bag of words), not that I implemented them.

Comment: What labeled *training* data do you have?

Comment: nothing actually. I don't have a training data set.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You said:

> All the algorithms I've checked so far e.g. n-grams variants, bag of
>   words etc. are only used for clustering strings that are part of a
>   context but here is not the case.

However, those algorithms can still be used if you don't treat tokens as full words, but as combinations of characters instead.

Here is an example of such algorithm in Python using Sklearn.

```
from sklearn.feature_extraction.text import TfidfVectorizer
from sklearn.cluster import KMeans

data = [
    'alex@examplemail.com',
    'bernard@examplemail.com',
    'chris@newmail.com',
    'dorothy@nemail.com',
    'emily@examplemail.com'
]

X = TfidfVectorizer(analyzer='char').fit_transform(data)

kmeans = KMeans(n_clusters=2).fit(X)

for cluster in set(kmeans.labels_):
    print('\nCluster: {}'.format(cluster))
    for i, label in enumerate(kmeans.labels_):
        if label == cluster:
            print(data[i])

> Cluster: 0
> alex@examplemail.com
> bernard@examplemail.com
> emily@examplemail.com
> 
> Cluster: 1
> chris@newmail.com
> dorothy@nemail.com
```

The major trick is `TfidfVectorizer(analyzer='char')`, where you don't treat **n-grams** of words, but of characters instead.

P.S. If you at some point want to use word n-grams (if you have generally well written sentences) you can use `TfidfVectorizer(analyzer='word')`.